# No a type declaration for the last mongo versions

Tags: mongodb, typescript, server

I am developing a server side node based application transformed by TypeScript. I use mongo as the database. I use a npm library mongodb to work with the database. It does not contains declarations. There is a package @types/mongodb. I am confused that the upper version of mongo support is 3.1. Even docker hub does not have a container with such version. Could you suppose what I should do with? I see that TypeScript is not a good idea for server side. I've chosen it because Angular is used on the project.

Comment: How do you conclude that the upper version of Mongo support is 3.1?  The major and minor versions of `@types/mongodb` correspond to those of the `mongodb` package, not the Mongo server.

Comment: I read comments in a declaration file after I've got problems with typings. There is the same file https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongodb/index.d.ts I also can not believe in it.

Comment: What problem did you have with the typings?  Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Everything works as it was designed. It was my personal mistake. I created an index for a collection without defining the collection.

```
await db.collection(this.collectionName).createIndex({'key': 1}, {unique: true});
```

But what I have written is still actual, It is the explicit definition. How does one file support all versions? I guess there still are some definition problem during downgrade. Thank you to everybody.